# Accept all JSON from the request AKKA-HTTTP

Tags: json, scala, marshalling, akka-http, spray-json

I have one route:

```
val receiveMessage = post {
  path("receive_message"){
    entity(as[Receive]) {
      message => {
        println(message)
        complete("ok")
      }
    }
  }
}
```

He work with case class:

```
// spray (JSON marshalling)
import akka.http.scaladsl.marshallers.sprayjson.SprayJsonSupport._
import spray.json.DefaultJsonProtocol._

    final case class Receive(notification_text: String)
    // formats for unmarshalling and marshalling
    implicit val itemFormat4 = jsonFormat1(Receive)
```

Is there a way to make a route that can receive any JSON objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can type your route to receive a `JsObject` (from SprayJson):

```scala
entity(as[JsObject])
```